# shadow copies of non-shared folders on 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, vss

First, sorry for the bad english.

There is something I can't figure out about VSS on Windows Server 2008 R2 : 
I have been asked to get a previous version of a file, which is located on a non-shared folder.

In every snapshot of the file, it has the same size, although the MD5 sig differs...

I would like to know if only the files / folders in shares are concerned by the feature ?
I just deleted a folder on my server account desktop (accessed with TSE), and I could restore it without any problem...

Really can't figure out why it works on my non-shared desktop but not on another folder (which is located on the same volume).

Thanks for your help !

Jérémie

Comment: I thought your English was fine.  Just sayin.